# How to determine if a page is being redirected

Tags: python, http, http-headers

I need to check whether a page is being redirected or not without actually downloading the content. I just need the final URL. What's the best way of doing this is Python?
Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you specifically want to avoid downloading the content, you'll need to use the HEAD request method.  I believe the `urllib` and `urllib2` libraries do not support HEAD requests, so you'll have to use the lower-level `httplib` library:

```
import httplib

h = httplib.HTTPConnection('www.example.com')
h.request('HEAD', '/')
response = h.getresponse()

// Check for 30x status code
if 300 <= response.status < 400:
    // It's a redirect
    location = response.getheader('Location')
```

Comment: Great. I was trying to force urllib/urllib2 to do this without much luck, and httplib's documentation isn't the best. Thanks!

Comment: @Adam It looks like you can do it with `urllib2`. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421170/python-head-request-with-urllib2).

Answer (score 1):

When you open the URL with `urllib2`, and you're redirected, you get a status 30x for redirection.  Check the info to see the location to which you're redirected.  You don't need to read the page to read the `info()` that's part of the response.

Comment: Does urllib2 give you a way to issue a HEAD command?  That's usually the way to get just the information you need without the network overhead of transmitting the page contents.

Comment: You don't have to read the page.  Your response includes a socket which you can simply close.

Comment: Yes, but you're still incurring network traffic.  The point of HEAD is to not incur the network traffic.