# Making HTTP HEAD request with urllib2 from Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2, head

I'm trying to do a HEAD request of a page using Python 2.

I am trying

```
import misc_urllib2
.....
opender = urllib2.build_opener([misc_urllib2.MyHTTPRedirectHandler(), misc_urllib2.HeadRequest()])
```

with `misc_urllib2.py` containing

```
class HeadRequest(urllib2.Request):
    def get_method(self):
        return "HEAD"


class MyHTTPRedirectHandler(urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler):
    def __init__ (self):
        self.redirects = []

    def http_error_301(self, req, fp, code, msg, headers):  
        result = urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler.http_error_301(
                self, req, fp, code, msg, headers)
        result.redirect_code = code
        return result

    http_error_302 = http_error_303 = http_error_307 = http_error_301
```

But I am getting

```
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

If I just do

```
opender = urllib2.build_opener(misc_urllib2.MyHTTPRedirectHandler())
```

then it works fine

Answer (score 59, accepted):

This works just fine:

```
import urllib2
request = urllib2.Request('http://localhost:8080')
request.get_method = lambda : 'HEAD'

response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
print response.info()
```

Tested with quick and dirty HTTPd hacked in python:

```
Server: BaseHTTP/0.3 Python/2.6.6
Date: Sun, 12 Dec 2010 11:52:33 GMT
Content-type: text/html
X-REQUEST_METHOD: HEAD
```

I've added a custom header field X-REQUEST_METHOD to show it works :)

Here is HTTPd log:

```
Sun Dec 12 12:52:28 2010 Server Starts - localhost:8080
localhost.localdomain - - [12/Dec/2010 12:52:33] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Edit: there is also [httplib2](https://github.com/httplib2/httplib2)

```
import httplib2
h = httplib2.Http()
resp = h.request("http://www.google.com", 'HEAD')
```

Comment: Python3 (3.3+) added support for the `method` keyword argument to the [`Request` initializer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.Request.method) - as an alternative to bypass the need for the `lambda`

Answer (score 1):

Try httplib

```
>>> import httplib
>>> conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("www.google.com")
>>> conn.request("HEAD", "/index.html")
>>> res = conn.getresponse()
>>> print res.status, res.reason
200 OK
>>> print res.getheaders()
[('content-length', '0'), ('expires', '-1'), ('server', 'gws'), ('cache-control', 'private, max-age=0'), ('date', 'Sat, 20 Sep 2008 06:43:36 GMT'), ('content-type', 'text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1')]
```

See [How do you send a HEAD HTTP request in Python 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107405/how-do-you-send-a-head-http-request-in-python)

Comment: Does that allow you to set other request objs? See my OP, the MyHTTPRedirectHandler

Comment: We ran into a bug using this approach.  Later someone wanted to check an   HTTPS url, for which you have to use a different method: `httplib.HTTPSConnection()`

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies with your class HeadRequest, which inherits from urllib2.Request. According to doc, `urllib2.Request.__init__` signature is

```
 __init__(self, url, data=None, headers={}, origin_req_host=None, unverifiable=False)
```

so you must pass an url argument to it. In your second try, you just do not use HeadRequest, this is why it works.

Answer (score 0):

you shoud not add `HeadRequest` to `build_opener` or `add_handler` it should be called like this

```
opener = urllib2.build_opener(MyHTTPRedirectHandler)
response = opener.open(HeadRequest(url))
print response.getheaders()
```