# using python urllib how to avoid non HTML content

Tags: python, content-type, urllib, limits

I am using urllib (note not urllib2) and getting title of pages from user supplied urls. Unfortunately sometimes the url is not an HTML but some huge file or some very long running process on the remote site.

I have checked the python docs but urllib is limited and looking at the source it seems I could change it but I cannot do so on the server. there is mention of info() but no example on  how to implement it.

I am using FancyURLopener which I guess is not available in urllib2 and I dont know if urllib2 can solve the problem

1. Is there way to define a socket timeout?
2. more importantly, how do I limit the request to HTML/XHTML content type only and ignore anything else totally i.e. I want to ensure the entire content is not downloaded

I am still going through urllib source and checking urllib2 but I am no expert on these tools.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Here](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#high-level-interface), it states that the `info()` method returns meta-information associated with the URL. You could use this to get the headers, and see what the Content-Type is (text/html), and if it's not what you want, discard the request.

```
>>> import urllib
>>> d = urllib.urlopen('http://www.google.com/')
>>> try:
...     if d.info()['content-type'].startswith('text/html'):
...             print 'its html'
...     else:
...             print 'its not html'
... except KeyError:
...     print 'its not html'
... 
its html
```

I've hacked together something quick to allow specifying a `HEAD` request for you in `urllib`. :)

```
import urllib
import socket
from urllib import unwrap, toBytes, quote, splittype, splithost, splituser, unquote, addinfourl

class MyURLOpener(urllib.FancyURLopener):
    def open_http(self, url, data=None, method=None):
        """Use HTTP protocol."""
        import httplib
        user_passwd = None
        proxy_passwd= None
        if isinstance(url, str):
            host, selector = splithost(url)
            if host:
                user_passwd, host = splituser(host)
                host = unquote(host)
            realhost = host
        else:
            host, selector = url
            # check whether the proxy contains authorization information
            proxy_passwd, host = splituser(host)
            # now we proceed with the url we want to obtain
            urltype, rest = splittype(selector)
            url = rest
            user_passwd = None
            if urltype.lower() != 'http':
                realhost = None
            else:
                realhost, rest = splithost(rest)
                if realhost:
                    user_passwd, realhost = splituser(realhost)
                if user_passwd:
                    selector = "%s://%s%s" % (urltype, realhost, rest)
                if proxy_bypass(realhost):
                    host = realhost

            #print "proxy via http:", host, selector
        if not host: raise IOError, ('http error', 'no host given')

        if proxy_passwd:
            import base64
            proxy_auth = base64.b64encode(proxy_passwd).strip()
        else:
            proxy_auth = None

        if user_passwd:
            import base64
            auth = base64.b64encode(user_passwd).strip()
        else:
            auth = None
        h = httplib.HTTP(host)

        if method is not None:
            h.putrequest(method, selector)
        else:
            h.putrequest('GET', selector)

        if data is not None:
            #h.putrequest('POST', selector)
            h.putheader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
            h.putheader('Content-Length', '%d' % len(data))

        if proxy_auth: h.putheader('Proxy-Authorization', 'Basic %s' % proxy_auth)
        if auth: h.putheader('Authorization', 'Basic %s' % auth)
        if realhost: h.putheader('Host', realhost)
        for args in self.addheaders: h.putheader(*args)
        h.endheaders(data)
        errcode, errmsg, headers = h.getreply()
        fp = h.getfile()
        if errcode == -1:
            if fp: fp.close()
            # something went wrong with the HTTP status line
            raise IOError, ('http protocol error', 0,
                            'got a bad status line', None)
        # According to RFC 2616, "2xx" code indicates that the client's
        # request was successfully received, understood, and accepted.
        if (200 <= errcode < 300):
            return addinfourl(fp, headers, "http:" + url, errcode)
        else:
            if data is None:
                return self.http_error(url, fp, errcode, errmsg, headers)
            else:
                return self.http_error(url, fp, errcode, errmsg, headers, data)

    def open(self, fullurl, data=None, method=None):
        """Use URLopener().open(file) instead of open(file, 'r')."""
        fullurl = unwrap(toBytes(fullurl))
        # percent encode url, fixing lame server errors for e.g, like space
        # within url paths.
        fullurl = quote(fullurl, safe="%/:=&?~#+!$,;'@()*[]|")
        if self.tempcache and fullurl in self.tempcache:
            filename, headers = self.tempcache[fullurl]
            fp = open(filename, 'rb')
            return addinfourl(fp, headers, fullurl)
        urltype, url = splittype(fullurl)
        if not urltype:
            urltype = 'file'
        if urltype in self.proxies:
            proxy = self.proxies[urltype]
            urltype, proxyhost = splittype(proxy)
            host, selector = splithost(proxyhost)
            url = (host, fullurl) # Signal special case to open_*()
        else:
            proxy = None
        name = 'open_' + urltype
        self.type = urltype
        name = name.replace('-', '_')
        if not hasattr(self, name):
            if proxy:
                return self.open_unknown_proxy(proxy, fullurl, data)
            else:
                return self.open_unknown(fullurl, data)
        try:
            return getattr(self, name)(url, data, method)
        except socket.error, msg:
            raise IOError, ('socket error', msg), sys.exc_info()[2]


opener = MyURLOpener()

# NOTE: including any data no longer implicitly makes the method POST,
#       so you must now specify the method to POST if you include data
# NOTE: this overrides only open_http, and not open_https, but you can
#       use a similar technique, and override open_https as well

d = opener.open('http://www.google.com/', method='HEAD')
```

Comment: I infact do. I was working on making it for you. Here it is. :)

Comment: Note that the entire page will still be downloaded in order to find the `content-type` header. To get around that, you can do a `HEAD` request instead of a `GET` request, but I haven't found out a way to do that with `urllib`.

Comment: @JohnDoe: Your solution is even better than you claim. You can use it to inspect the headers without downloading the entire file. For example, if you point it at `http://python.org/ftp/python/3.2.2/Python-3.2.2.tar.bz2`, you can look at `d.info()` (almost instantly) without downloading all 11MBs.

Comment: Nice. That is certainly useful in such a case. I still hacked together a way to use methods with `urllib` though. The other (less hacky) way, can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107405/how-do-you-send-a-head-http-request-in-python) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421170/python-head-request-with-urllib2). For all intents and purposes though, unutbu's method should work fine from the sounds of it.

Comment: I can confirm what unutbu said. info must be implicitly using HEAD. I just tried it this as well. John Doe, can't thank you enough.

Comment: just saw your hack, if you can do that rather quickly... you must be awesome at python and possibly a jedi

Comment: It's nothing more than a verbatim copy of some `urllib` code, except with edits. :)