# How do I get HTTP header info without authentication using python?

Tags: python, http, authentication, http-headers

I'm trying to write a small program that will simply display the header information of a website. Here is the code:

```
import urllib2

url = 'http://some.ip.add.ress/'

request = urllib2.Request(url)

try:
    html = urllib2.urlopen(request)
except urllib2.URLError, e:
    print e.code
else:
    print html.info()
```

If 'some.ip.add.ress' is google.com then the header information is returned without a problem. However if it's an ip address that requires basic authentication before access then  it returns a 401. Is there a way to get header (or any other) information without authentication?

---

**I've worked it out.**

After try has failed due to unauthorized access the following modification will print the header information:

```
print e.info()
```

*instead of:*

```
print e.code()
```

Thanks for looking :)

Comment: It's ok i've worked it out. print e.info() on error

Still learning python....

Comment: Post your solution as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want just the headers, instead of using `urllib2`, you should go lower level and use [`httplib`](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html)

```
import httplib
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(host)
conn.request("HEAD", path)
print conn.getresponse().getheaders()
```

Comment: I tired that before and received a 401. Your method works great! Thanks for that

Comment: I seem to be having problems again, the python console is returning _[Errno 104] Connection reset by peer_ and i'm not sure what this means. I'm the peer but i'm not resetting anything, am i!?

Comment: Most likely means, that the other end is not accepting HTTP connections.

Comment: You'd think so but i can access and log in via my chrome browser just fine. Also my orginal code (at the top) works fine and returns the headers no problem! Straaaange

Comment: Instead of going low level I think it would be better to show how to do `HEAD` request using urllib2.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want are HTTP headers then you should make `HEAD` not `GET` request. You can see how to do this by reading [Python - HEAD request with urllib2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421170/).